# Can't detect webViewDidFinishLoad event

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, swift3

I'm trying to make an IOS app to show a web site in a webview.
That's ok it's working. Now I'm trying to detect the end of the page load.
That's my code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var my_web_view: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var my_loading_view: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSLog("----------------> START");

        my_web_view.scrollView.bounces = false;
        my_web_view.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true;

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.sortirauhavre.com/");
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!);
        my_web_view.delegate = self;
        my_web_view.loadRequest(request);
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!){
        NSLog("----------------> STOP");
    }
}
```

In my console I can read "START" but never "STOP". Xcode don't say me I made an error, do you know what am I doing wrong please ?

Comment: your url load the data or not

Comment: My webview display the website succefully :)

Comment: exactly dont know but no need of this `self.view.addSubview(my_web_view);`

Comment: call this one in `my_web_view.delegate = self;` before this `my_web_view.loadRequest(request);`

Comment: Tryed, doesn't work :P (But thanks a lot)

Comment: is this possbile to attach your project

Comment: Do you mean a zip of my project ? A link ?

Comment: whatever choice is yours

Comment: http://rgbtohexconvert.com/Sortir_au_Havre.zip

Comment: done , now it  works

Comment: Now it works ? I don't understand. Didi you edit my project to make it works ?

Comment: yes , you are not connected the delegate of your webview to current class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes , the problem you are not connected the delegate of your webview to current class

[image]

and call the delegate as

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
    NSLog("----------------> STOP");
}
```

you get the output as

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your experience and your time <3